# Performance of static const variable in shader

Tags: shaders

I am using static const variables based on uniform variables. For example:

```
uniform uint uSampleCount;

static const float invSampleCount = 1.0 / float(uSampleCount);
```

Is this static recalculated for every vertex and fragment, or are shader frameworks smart enough to initialize this once before the shader starts processing? Does using or not using static and/or const make a difference?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your shader with and without these keywords to find out for sure? I'd trust direct reproducible measurement over "someone on the Internet said...." any day. ;)

Comment: Yes, haven't seen a difference. Was hoping someone had some documentation link or something that I haven't been able to find in a few hours of Google searching. I am considering moving a lot more into these kind of statics but want to be sure of the performance characteristics moving forward.

Comment: Try moving a lot into that style now, with very expensive operations, to stress test it. I'd bet you could complete such a test faster than waiting for an answer, and be more confident in the conclusion as a bonus.

Comment: I'd be intersted in having the results of that experient posted as an answer though :)